# How can i convert specific characters in a string and in a specific index

Tags: python, string

For example i have the string "alba iuliara" and what i want to do is to convert all the "a" with "A" but not the first and the last "a". The result must be "albA iuliAra"

Any idea how can i do that using a statement like while, if and etc..

Comment: Are you willing to use a regular expression?

Comment: Please edit the question to show us the code for your latest attempt and where you got stuck. See also: [ask] and [help/on-topic].

Comment: Do you mean to exclude the first and last character of the string, or the first and last occurrence?

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty easy if you use the replace method.

### Code if you don't consider the first and last characters

```
your_string = "alba iuliara"
your_string = f"{your_string[0]}{your_string[1:-1].replace('a','A')}{your_string[-1]}"
print(your_string)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        your_string = "Namaskara"
        rep_char='a'
        occ1=your_string.find(rep_char)   #Searches for first occurence of replacing character
        occn=your_string.rfind(rep_char) #Searches for last occurence of replacing character
    
    #from startig poition of string to your first occurence of character  and last occurence of character to end of the string nothing will be replaced. for remaining string character will be replaced with uppercase
        your_string = f"{your_string[0:occ1+1]}{your_string[occ1+1:occn].replace(rep_char,rep_char.upper())}{your_string[occn:]}"
    
        print(your_string)

output: NamAskAra
```

I have used @jock logic but modified to make it generic.